# sort array of dictionaries by it's values - swift programmatically

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of dictionaries like this:

`var uidTimestampsNotSorted = [[String: Timestamp]]()`

and I want to sort the dictionaries by the value of the dictionary `Timestamp`, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: But there is only one key "Timestamp", or there are multiple keys, and you also have to find the key corresponding to the "Timesamp". Could you share some input sample?

Comment: there's only one key of type Timestamp and I need to order the array of dictionaries from the earliest timestamp to the latest

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to sort the timestamps themselves, then something like this example might do it:

```
let dicts: [[String: Int]] = [
    ["a":1, "b": 2, "c": 3],
    ["A":10, "B": 20, "C": 30],
    ["AA":100, "BB": 200, "CC": 300],
]

let vs = dicts.flatMap(\.values).sorted(by: >)
```

With an appropriate sorting function

Comment: I need to sort the array of dictionaries knowing that the value is only one timestamp for dictionary.
I need to order the key value pair starting from the earliest timestamp finishing with the latest

Comment: like this?   let vs = dicts.sorted { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    (lhs["timestamp"] ?? 0) < (rhs["timestamp"] ?? 0)
}

Comment: thank you! it works